# Looping through table rows with Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

So what I'm trying to do is get the last row of an HTML table. If this row then has a certain class I will ignore this row and select the previous one. This would then be cycled through from the end of the table until a row was found without this certain class.

I figured it's probably involving a for loop, a check for the row class and then JQuery's row.prev method, but still not quite sure how to approach this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's on the server-side generating the Html table?

Comment: With jQuery it's a one-liner as shown below. Without jQuery it's still only about three or four lines using a for loop over the [`table.rows` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.rows), checking the class and breaking out of the loop when found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've got the following HTML:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="YouFoundMe">
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="certainclass">
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="certainclass">
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="certainclass">
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can do this:

```
var elWithoutClass = $('#mytable tr:not(.certainclass):last');

if (elWithoutClass.length) {
    alert(elWithoutClass.get(0).id);
    // alerts "YouFoundMe"
}
```

- `:not(.certainclass)` will eliminate `<tr>` without class 'certainclass'
- `:last` will get you the last one

I invite you to check the [Selectors documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) of jquery to learn more about them.

Answer (score 3):

To get the last table row that doesn't have a certain class, say `targetClass`, you can do this:

```
$("tr:not(.targetClass):last");
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with this table row, but if you were to add `targetClass` to the last row that didn't have it, it would look like this

```
$("tr:not(.targetClass):last").addClass("targetClass");
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nm2RG/) to see it in action

Answer (score 2):

This example shows you how to get the last  of each table on the current page: http://jsfiddle.net/JBnzK/

```
$('table').find('tr:last').each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('stupid')) {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    } else {
        $(this).css('color', 'green');
    }
});
```